# De que manera consigo un valor innerHTML en React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Esto es una calculadora sencilla, comencé con React hace poco y se que la utilidad de la misma es para no trabajar directamente con el DOM, pero tengo este problema.

```javascript
function Calculator(props){

    const show = () =>{
        let number = document.querySelector('.button');
        setAnswer(answer+ number.innerHTML)
    };
    const [answer,setAnswer] = useState('');

    return(
        <div className="component">
            <div className="calculator-component">
                <div className="calculator-component-answer">
                    {answer}
                </div>
                <div className="calculator-component-conteiner">
                    <div className="row">
                        <button onClick={show} className="button">1</button>
                        <button onClick={show} className="button">2</button>
                        <button onClick={show} className="button">3</button>
                        <button onClick={show} className="button">+</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );  
};

export default Calculator;
```

Comment: Cuál es el problema?

Answer (score 1):

Bienvenid@ a la comunidad,

Se puede usar el atributo `value` del elemento button y `react syntetic event` para pasar el `event object` como parametro a la función handler `onClick`, luego se extrae el valor para cada botón en específico:

```
export default function App() {
  
  const [answer, setAnswer] = useState('');
  const show = (event) =>{
    //let number = document.querySelector('.button');
    let { value } = event.target;
    console.log(value)
    //setAnswer(answer+ number.innerHTML)
  };

  return(
      <div className="component">
          <div className="calculator-component">
              <div className="calculator-component-answer">
                  {answer}
              </div>
              <div className="calculator-component-conteiner">
                  <div className="row">
                      <button onClick={show} className="button" value="1" >1</button>
                      <button onClick={show} className="button" value="2" >2</button>
                      <button onClick={show} className="button" value="3" >3</button>
                      <button onClick={show} className="button" value="4" >+</button>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  );  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Es bastante sencillo, solo desde de usar `useRef`, esto viene siendo una variable distinta a `useState` o las por defecto de JavaScript

```
import { useRef } from 'react'

function Component() {
  const ref = userRef(null)
}
```

como puedes ver la sintaxis es bastante sencilla, `useRef` puede almacenar información de Elementos JSX gracias al atributo `ref`

```
return (
  <div ref={ref}></div>
)
```

esto guardará su referencia, gracias a eso tendrás acceso a toda su información con `ref.current` dentro de un `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
  !ref?.current && return

  console.log(ref.current.innerHTML) 
}, [])
```

Así puedes acceder al `innerHTML` sin necesidad de usar `querySelector` o un `getElement`

Y si te lo preguntas también puedes hacer esto: `ref.current.addEventListener()` es válido porque estás accediendo al elemento como tal.

Recuerda siempre hacerlo dentro de un `useEffect` para que él `red` pueda obtener el elemento, el `useEffect` lo que hará es esperar a que se pinte por primera vez el DOM, entonces podrás obtener el elemento y podrás interactuar con él.

Te invito a hacer un `console.log(ref)` dentro de un `useEffect` para que veas todos los atributos que tiene.

`Disclaimer`: va a llegar un momento que tendrás más 1 `ref`, llámalos de esta forma: `nombreIndentificadorRef`, así sabrás que es un `ref` y a que le hace `ref`